# Calculate width with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Depending on amout of `<div clas="product"></div>` I'm trying to set width for .productholder

```
 <div class="productholder">
    <div clas="product"></div>
    <div clas="product"></div>
    <div clas="product"></div>
    <div clas="product"></div>
    <div clas="product"></div>
 </div>
```

I can set fix width for .product if this will help.

I have tried this, but don't seems to be working:

```
var width = 0;
$('.product').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.productholder').css('width', width + 250);
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: missing an `s` on `class` in each of `<div class="product">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a unit?

```
var width = 0;
$('.product').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.productholder').css('width', width + 250 + 'px');
```

By the way, `<div class="productholder">` width will grow to accommodate the width of the inner `<div>` elements

**EDIT:**

Your code does work as is - **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/anuvi)**. Add **/edit** to the URL to see the code.

Does `<div class="productholder">` have any text content? Are you specifying a height for it?

Comment: i tried that. Div is absolute in relative container. Product themselves are floating; Div will not extend due to the fact that the div holding it has fixed width

Comment: My stupidity! Sorry. Messed something up in .js file. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
 var holder = $('.productholder');
 var width = holder.find('.product').length * 250;
 holder.css('width', width + "px");
```